# What punctuation to use after an incomplete sentence to introduce a list of items?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I want to use an incomplete sentence to introduce a list of items but I could not find any punctuation guide on this. If I remember correctly, I have seen people using hyphens for it.

Example:
If you would like proceed, please indicate-

1. whether you are 18 or above;
2. whether you have enough deposit in your account; and
3. the effective date for the changes.

I would like to know if the hyphen after "indicate" is used correctly. And should I capitalize the first word of each item. Thanks a lot.

Edit: Thank you for your help. However, my confusion here is that, in my example, **"please indicate" can be paired up the any of the three items in list to form a complete and independent sentence, e.g. "please indicate whether you are 18 or above."**

The example of the usage of colon I saw in the related posts is not quite the same:

There are two types of insects:

(a) white

(b) black

"There are two types of insects white" is not a correct sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you put a semicolon after an and in a list with bullets? Example in body](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/518681/can-you-put-a-semicolon-after-an-and-in-a-list-with-bullets-example-in-body) (Sven Yargs gives the CMoS and OxfordSG recommendations on punctuating bulleted/numbered lists, and both recommend a colon before the first bullet point).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What punctuation belongs before a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13484/what-punctuation-belongs-before-a-list) Also [Comma and Semicolon Use when Listing Items](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283834/comma-and-semicolon-use-when-listing-items), and other questions that should show up searching for list and punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a hyphen, or even an em dash (they're [different](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes/faq0002.html)), used in this way.

The punctuation would be much the same as if you didn't have numbers:

> If you would like proceed, please indicate whether you are 18 or above, whether you have enough deposit in your account, and
> the effective date for the changes.

or

> If you would like proceed, please indicate:  whether you are 18 or above; whether you have enough deposit in your account; and
> the effective date for the changes.

The colon, using semicolons as you already do, is a [common](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/colons/colons/) style. Replace the - above with a : and nobody will raise an eyebrow. :)